# Spring boot multi module servletDispatchers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-boot

I have a following project structure

```
-Project
 |-config
 |  |-modules
 |     |-admin
 |     |-web
 |- platform
```

Platform is the project that contains the spring-boot start class,
Platform has a dependency on config and config had dependencies on everything in the directory modules
Platform is also the module that gets started with the mvn spring-boot:run command.

The thing I am trying to accomplish is that the modules admin and web (both web apps) have their own mapping like

- /admin
- /web

The following code represents an controller in the admin module, the web module also contains a similar controller (thats the point)

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String adminController() {
       return "admin";
    }
}
```

Here some code for the configuration of the admin module

```
@Configuration
public class Config implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

@Autowired
protected WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Autowired
protected ServerProperties server;

@Autowired(required = false)
protected MultipartConfigElement multipartConfig;

protected DispatcherServlet createDispatcherServlet() {

    AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext webContext = new AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext();
    webContext.setParent(webApplicationContext);
    webContext.scan("some.base.package");
    return new DispatcherServlet(webContext);
}

protected ServletRegistrationBean createModuleDispatcher(DispatcherServlet apiModuleDispatcherServlet) {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration =
            new ServletRegistrationBean(apiModuleDispatcherServlet,
                    "/admin");

    registration.setName("admin");
    registration.setMultipartConfig(this.multipartConfig);

    return registration;
}


@Bean(name = "adminsServletRegistrationBean")
public ServletRegistrationBean apiModuleADispatcherServletRegistration() {
    return createModuleDispatcher(createDispatcherServlet());
}

public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
    container.setContextPath("/admin");
}
}
```

Something similar goes for the web module

I have tried the implement the some of the given answers.

1. [Using multiple dispatcher servlets / web contexts with spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29200567/928591)
2. [Spring Boot (JAR) with multiple dispatcher servlets for different REST APIs with Spring Data REST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28499159/928591)
3. And lots of googling

When I let the component scan, scan both modules (removing the ComponentScan filter)

I get an a Ambiguous mapping found exception, saying that both controller methods dispatch to the same path "/"

But when disabling the component scan on one of the modules, then indeed the admin modules get mapped to /admin.

when I disable both controllers, I see that the /web and /admin dispatchServlets get mapped.

So I understand the exception but I dont understand how to resolve this.
For me its a must that I can do this per module and I dont want to map it using

```
@RequestMapping("/admin")
```

on the controller class

I also tried specifying the contextPath and servletPath in the application.properties

So my question is: what would be the best approach to reach my goal, or am I trying to use spring-boot for something it was not ment for.

**Edit**
A Proof of concept would be nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I found the solution.
You can take a look here at this [link](https://bitbucket.org/maikelbollemeijer/saneium-poc/overview)

You`ll have to register the dispatcher servlets in the main application and dont use the @SpringBootApplication annotation.

For a complete example just checkout the project and check the code

**EDIT:** later this week ill provide a detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is that put your AdminController and WebController in separate packages.

```
some.base.admin.package
some.base.web.package
```

And in the corresponding configurations scan only your required package to register the DispatcherServlet

Admin Config

```
webContext.scan("some.base.admin.package");
```

Web Config

```
webContext.scan("some.base.web.package");
```

This way in the corresponding `WebApplicationContext` for each `DispatcherServlet` only one mapping will be available for `"/"`

Comment: I have them in separate packages, separate modules even. and the scan approach did not work for me either.